# Delete Azure DevOps/VSTS project permanently

Tags: project, devops, delete-file

I removed my old projects in my visualstudio.com account but I can see them in the Visual Studio.

[image]

How can I delete a project/branch permanently?

Answer (score 0):

deleting the project through wit admin command.
Sometimes while deleting through GUI the project still reflects , as the project may still be present in the database.

Comment: witadmin is used for work items not for the project related operations or am I wrong?

Comment: Sorry I meant use the cmd prompt to delete the vsts project. The command is there on Microsoft document. Once u do that it will get deleted from the DB too.